# Running an executable file through Cygwin

Tags: c, windows, bash, gcc

I've recently opened up Head First C and I was having an issue with one of the programs. (I'm using Windows)

I saved a cards.c file in my Documents folder under a folder named Practice and navigated to that folder within Cygwin

I compiled using **gcc cards.c -o cards** and it compiled with no errors, so I tried to type **cards** to run the exe file but I got -bash: cards: command not found.

I read through several stackoverflow answers and tried multiple suggestions such as ./a exe, /a exe, cards.exe, a cards, etc/bin/cards and more, but I could only run the file with **/cygdrive/c/Me/Documents/Practice/cards.exe**

I'm somewhat new with Cygwin so I'm wondering if there is something I missed or a better way to go about this? I'm really looking to learn. On a side note I'm wondering if copying cygwin1.dll from the cygwin bin file to the folder containing the exe file will help, but I don't know how to access the bin file to copy it.

Comment: Try `./cards`.  But if you want to avoid this awkward syntax, you should add `.` to your `PATH`.  That way you can just type `cards` next time.

Comment: Make sure the program is executable with "chmod +x cards". Then use "./cards" to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the output file will be named cards, not cards.exe
2. there are a few different ways to execute that file, here are some of those ways.

   a) `. cards`    <-- notice the leading '. '

   b) at the cygwin command line in the directory where 'cards' is located:

   ```
    chmod cards 777
    cards
   ```

   c) from the directory where cards is located:

   ```
     ./cards
   ```

Suggest the b) method since it is a permanent fix

Comment: 3) add the correct dir to the PATH env variable, i.e. `PATH="/cygdrive/c/Me/Documents/Practice:$PATH"`. good luck to all.